# como crear una vista de una tabla diferente a otra base de datos?

Tags: sql-server

Quisiera utilizar los datos de una tabla diferente en otra BD en la misma instancia, como hago para crear un vista para poder manejar dichos datos? gracias

estoy usando el ejemplo de que me mando el primer user y no me funciona

```
SELECT * FROM [NOMBRE BASE DE DATOS].[dbo].[NOMBRE DE LA TABLA]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso que mostras, es porque solo ejecuto lo seleccionado.. probaste ejecutar toda la query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si entendí bien tu pregunta. Si lo que quieres es usar, ver o consultar tablas, vistas u otros de otra base de datos, tendrías que poner como prefijo de la tabla o vista que quieres consultar, la base de datos a la que pertenece. Al menos en SQL Server, no sé que base de datos estás utilizando.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM [NOMBRE BASE DE DATOS].[dbo].[NOMBRE DE LA TABLA]
```

También podrías usar al principio de la query: `Use [NOMBRE DE LA BASE DE DATOS};`

Comment: @Nacido de la bruma si eso quiero hacer y siguiendo el ejemplo me sale error

Comment: Prueba introducir el [dbo] en medio: 

`select * from Geoloca.[dbo].garantia`

Usa Atium si tienes para anticiparte a los errores.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas para crear una vista como necesitas seria mas o menos asi:

```
CREATE VIEW `nombre_vista` AS SELECT * FROM DDBB_NAME.TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: Gracias eso buscaba